# Accessing member variables through static pointer to instance

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

I have a class with a static vector of pointers to all instances of the class. When I access the member variables through a static getter method, I sometimes get wrong results.

Code:
hpp-file:

```
class ObjectID {
    public:
        ObjectID();
        float getShininess() const { return m_shininess; }
        static const std::shared_ptr<ObjectID> getID(unsigned long);
    private:
        float m_shininess;
        static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ObjectID>> s_ids;
}
```

cpp-file:

```
static std::mutex s_mutex;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ObjectID>> ObjectID::s_ids = {};

const std::shared_ptr<ObjectID> ObjectID::getID(unsigned long id) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mutex);
    std::shared_ptr<ObjectID> ptr = s_ids.at(id - 1);
    return ptr;
}

ObjectID::ObjectID()
  : m_shininess(50.f)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mutex);
    s_ids.emplace_back(this);
}
```

I have a suspicion that it has something to do with the fact that I use two threads. However adding the mutex did not change anything.

For clarification, one thread creates ObjectIDs and another thread calls

```
ObjectID::getID(id)->getShininess();
```

I don't always get 50, sometimes I get 1, and I am never changing m_shininess.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

ObjectIDs are created in another class, which has a vector of ObjectIDs.

```
m_objects.emplace_back();
```

Comment: How do you know that which ids are valid?

Comment: How do you know the `this` in `s_ids.emplace_back(this);` is even *dynamically* allocated?

Comment: @nosid: In the cpp-file, I added it to the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig -- exactly, this could fail either if the ObjectID is created on the stack, or if it's created and bound to a shared_ptr outside the constructor.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I thought "this" was a pointer to the instance?

Comment: @nosid: I am not changing m_shininess anywhere.

Comment: pointers existing to something does not mean the object is on the free store.  If you create any automatuc storage instances (on 'the stack') the above code will do undefined behaviour 6 ways from sunday

Comment: @gartenriese It is, but code like : `ObjectID id;` will wrap a `std::shared_ptr<>` around a non-dynamically-allocated instance, which will invoke undefined behavior as soon as the default deleter fires on that pointer. Likely the only reason you're not seeing catastrophe until shutdown is because there is nothing apparent that ever *removes* those ill-formed `std::shared_pointer<>`s from the collection (until default destruction of the static vector at process shutdown).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Ok, that makes sense. How can I do it then?

Comment: @gartenriese as soon as my Mac finishes installing it's update I'll try and post a viable id-to-object solution. Likely someone else will do it first, however (not exactly the fastest Mac in the world).

Comment: @WhozCraig: dlf's answer worked for me, but I am still interested in your approach!

Comment: @gartenriese that is similar to how I would likely do it, in particular the hiding of the constructor. if this is multi-threaded you still need to protect `s_ids` during both modification and querying, but the model is sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector holds shared_ptr, but you are emplacing raw pointers to ObjectID (this) into it. Since shared_ptrs can be constructed from raw ones this compiles, but it probably isn't doing what you want it to. In particular, you will wind up with wild pointers in that vector if an ObjectID gets destroyed though other means. I don't know for sure that this is the cause of your problem, but it is at least suspicious.

I don't know your exact requirements, but maybe something like this would help?

```
class ObjectID
{
public:
   static std::shared_ptr<ObjectID> Create()
   {
       auto created = std::make_shared<ObjectID>();
       s_ids.push_back(created);
       return created;
   }  

private:
   ObjectID()
   {
      // as before
   }
};
```

Comment: Okay, I guess I need a better solution then. However, I am not destroying any ObjectIDs, at least not to my knowledge!

Comment: Agreed.  This could also be a problem if the ObjectID objects get assigned to a shared_ptr outside the constructor.  They will have separate ownership counts and once one of the two goes to zero it will blast the object even if there's a reference to the raw pointer elsewhere.  If you post more of your code where you are creating the ObjectID values we might be able to help more.

Comment: @gartenriese: How are they being kept alive? And how are they constructed in the first place?

Comment: @mwigdahl: I added information about how I create the ObjectIDs.

Comment: If you want the static vector to keep them alive, you could replace the public ObjectID constructor with a static factory function that creates shared_ptr<ObjectId>, pushes the shared_ptr onto the vector, and then returns it (I edited my answer to show this).